# Need Help I'm moving a light switch from one wall to the other, but I ran into a problem

Tags: lighting, switch

[image: second picture of the way its wired now][image: please excuse the the dirty switch I haven't got a new switch yet this is the way it is at the moment]I recently moved into a house and I'm converting the attached Garage into a workshop. The thing is the light switch was on the other side of the Garage by the Garage door, I decided to move the switch closer to the door going into the house. I got the Box moved to were I want it and started the wiring process. The problem I have ran into is it seems to be a three way light switch. (only one switch turns on the lights no other switch to the indoor light) so I have 2 black 2 white 1 red and 1 ground wire. the light fixture does have an outlet on it and its a pull chain light fixture (planning on replacing the light fixture with an outlet and hanging up shop lights) when I was wiring it up I read on a different form to connect the 2 white wires, the two black wires with a third wire to connect to the switch and then put the red wire on the switch as well, (the light switch has no ground I'm going to get a new switch that has a ground on it.) I hooked everything up and flipped the breaker back on and tried the switch, I got nothing. I'm not an electrician nor do I have the money to hire a electrician. I'm stumped and annoyed at this. I know one wire has to be connect to power, then the other connected to the light fixture and outlet combo, or could I have it wrong and the fixture has the power going to it and the switch just completes the current, there is four wires the run to the light fixture, 2 black and the two from the switch box.

I'm sorry for the long paragraph I'm just trying to give as much detail as I can any help or tips would be greatly appreciated

EDIT: I went today and got a three way switch wired up everything and still nothing, i pulled the light fixture and seen about four or five black wired bundled and going on to the connection. a bundle of white wires and a red wire connected to the other terminal. i have two hot wires the red and one black going to the switch.

Comment: How was the old switch wired?

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the insides of the other boxes involved please?

Comment: @brhans there was a third wire going into a second switch. basically the two grounds were connected and that's the only different the black and white wire for the outside light was attached to the second light switch. and the ground from one of the current wires I'm using and the one to the outside light was connected.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel the light fixture or the box I'm having problems with? i edit the post and posted the pictures of the light switch. please excuse the filth but its 1 in the morning and no hardware stores are open.

Comment: @Allen -- all the boxes involved, really

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I sadly won't be able to show the light fixture tonight I would have to get someone to hold a flash light while I open the fixture up. A rough description is I have two black cables going into one side of the light fixtures, my guess it might be main power or coming off some other outlet. then inside of the light fixture its honestly a jumble and I couldn't quite figure out what cables went were the the two cable you see in the picture comes out and leads to the switch box. I'm very sorry I cant post a picture of the fixture right now I hope this helps